# How to select hashes from array of hashes that appears more than 2 times by a specified key

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to select `companies` when their `code` appears more than 2 times.

```
companies = [{code: 10, value: 3}, {code: 3, value: 5}, {code: 10, value: 4}, {code: 5, value: 10}]

companies.select{|c| companies.select{|c_inside| c_inside[:code] == c[:code]}.count > 1 }
=> [{:code=>10, :value=>3}, {:code=>10, :value=>4}]
```

This code works, but it seems a bit redundant. Is there better way to write the function like this?

Comment: The result array contains a company that appears *exactly* 2 times (not *more than*). Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
companies.group_by{ |hsh| hsh[:code] }
  .values
  .select{ |val| val.count > 1 }
  .flatten

#=> [{:code=>10, :value=>3}, {:code=>10, :value=>4}]
```

Comment: You can omit the `_k` argument if you move the `.values` call before the `.select` call.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've implemented this change.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way.

```
companies.group_by { |e| e[:code] }
         .select { |_, v| v.size > 1 }
         .flat_map { |_, v| v }
#=> [{:code=>10, :value=>3}, {:code=>10, :value=>4}]
```

Comment: @Stefan The code doesn't work without the backslashes. Alternativly you can move the dot to the end of the line before. But `rubocop` prefers the the backslash version.

Comment: It does work. A trailing backslash is only needed in a REPL like irb.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks. Works with 2.2.3 but not with 1.8.7.

Comment: IIRC, that syntax was introduces in Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

This code uses a n iterations instead of n^2 iterations:

```
companies = [{code: 10, value: 3}, {code: 3, value: 5}, {code: 10, value: 4}, {code: 5, value: 10}]
final_value = []
companies.each.with_object({}) do |c, hash|
  hash[c[:code]] = [] if hash[c[:code]] == nil
  hash[c[:code]] << c
  if hash[c[:code]].count == 2
    final_value += hash[c[:code]]
  elsif hash[c[:code]].count > 2
    final_value << c
  end
end

puts final_value
```